# Excel - Calculated Field IF Statement referencing a TEXT item

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Created a calculated field in a Excel Pivot table but when I reference a text dimension/column in the data source/cache being 'Title' it returns 0 when it should return 10 (This formula is just me playing around with calculated fields)

`= IF(Title="12 rounds",10,0)`

Answer (score 0):

A calculated field in a pivot table can't reference text values, it can only reference numbers, because pivot tables work by aggregation (e.g., adding numbers) and text can't be aggregated. Your best bet is probably to add a "helper column" to your source data to do the calculation (e.g., create a new column with the formula =IF(Title="12 rounds",10,0) in each cell), then use the helper column in the query. You should also be able to accomplish what you want with a power pivot, but that's more complicated.